# open() doesn't work when imported

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file in my `site-packages` directory called `wordlist.py` that consists of just one line:

```
f = open("words.txt")
```

There is a file called `words.txt` in the same directory. When I run `wordlist.py` it works fine. However, whenever I use `import wordlist`, I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'
```

I am using IDLE for Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use relative paths for file or directory names python will look for them (or create them) in your current working directory (the $PWD variable in bash).

if you want to have them relative to the current python file, you can use (python 3.4)

```
import pathlib
HERE = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
WORDS_PATH = HERE / '../path/to/words.txt'
with WORDS_PATH.open() as file_pointer:
    'do something with file_pointer...'
```